# Next and previous not working properly using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on the next and previous section. When I clicked on next button then it's displaying the next div but it's not working properly because Next button is working infinit.

Same as the previous button. I need to hide the previous button on page load when the user clicked on next button or scroll the mouse wheel than I have to display the previous button.

I tried some code

```js
new WOW().init();
 (function() {
    function scrollHorizontally(e) {
        e = window.event || e;
        var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
        document.getElementById('gentags').scrollLeft -= (delta*40); // Multiplied by 40
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    if (document.getElementById('gentags').addEventListener) {
        // IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
        document.getElementById('gentags').addEventListener("mousewheel", scrollHorizontally, false);
        // Firefox
        document.getElementById('gentags').addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", scrollHorizontally, false);
    } else {
        // IE 6/7/8
        document.getElementById('gentags').attachEvent("onmousewheel", scrollHorizontally);
    }
})();

$('.navigation_right').click(function() {
    $('.current').removeClass('current').hide()
        .next().show().addClass('current');
    if ($('.current').hasClass('last')) {
        $('.navigation_right').attr('disabled', true);
    }
    $('.navigation_left').attr('disabled', null);
});

$('.navigation_left').click(function() {
    $('.current').removeClass('current').hide()
        .prev().show().addClass('current');
    if ($('.current').hasClass('first')) {
        $('.navigation_left').attr('disabled', true);
    }
    $('.navigation_right').attr('disabled', null);
});
```

```css
  #gentags {
position:fixed;
margin-top: -.25em;
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}

#gentags > div{
    overflow: hidden;
    width:250%;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;  /* remove scrollbar space */
    background: transparent;  /* optional: just make scrollbar invisible */
}
/* optional: show position indicator in red */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: transparent;
}

.horizontal_scroll .full_screen_100 article{
    width: 11.58%;
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
    border-left: solid 1px #E2E2E2;

}
.active_div{

display: none;
}

  /*Navigation style*/
  .horizontal_scroll_icon_pre_next {
    bottom: 50px;
    left: 0;
    
    position: fixed;
    
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
   /* padding: 0 20px;*/
}
  .horizontal_scroll_icon_pre_next button{
  background-color: transparent;
border: none;
font-size: 0;
color: #7b7b7b;
display: none;
outline: 0;
cursor: pointer;
}
.horizontal_scroll_icon_pre_next button.navigation_left
{
 float: left;
}
.horizontal_scroll_icon_pre_next button.navigation_right
{
 float:right;
}

.horizontal_scroll_icon_pre_next button.active {
    display: block;
}
.horizontal_scroll_icon_pre_next button span {

    font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/animatecss/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.linearicons.com/free/1.0.0/icon-font.min.css"><!--icon-->
 <div class="active_div">
  <h2>I want to display this div when articles 7 comes on screen</h2>
 </div>

<div id="gentags">
<div class="horizontal_scroll">
  <div class="full_screen_100" id="left_scroll">
   <article class="wow fadeInUp first current"><div><p class="scroll_number">01</p><span class="page_slogan">Hover me and scroll mouse wheel</span></div></article>
   <article class="wow fadeInUp"><div><p class="scroll_number">02</p><span class="page_slogan">Hover me and scroll mouse wheel </span></div></article>
   <article class="wow fadeInUp"><div><p class="scroll_number">03</p><span class="page_slogan">Hover me and scroll mouse wheel</span></div></article>
   <article class="wow fadeInUp"><div><p class="scroll_number">04</p><span class="page_slogan">Hover me and scroll mouse wheel</span></div></article>
   <article class="wow fadeInUp"><div><p class="scroll_number">05</p><span class="page_slogan">Hover me and scroll mouse wheel</span></div></article>
   <article class="wow fadeInUp"><div><p class="scroll_number">06</p><span class="page_slogan">Hover me and scroll mouse wheel</span></div></article>
   <article class="wow fadeInUp"><div><p class="scroll_number">07</p><span class="page_slogan">Hover me and scroll mouse wheel</span></div></article>
   <article class="wow fadeInUp last"><div><p class="scroll_number">08</p><span class="page_slogan">Hover me and scroll mouse wheel</span></div></article>
 </div>
</div>
</div>


<div class="horizontal_scroll_icon_pre_next">
        <button class="navigation_left active"><span class="lnr lnr-arrow-left"></span>Previous</button>
        <button class="navigation_right active"><span class="lnr lnr-arrow-right"></span>Next</button>
    </div><!--horizontal_scroll_navigation-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.2/wow.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: First of all `$('#navigation_right')` should be `$('.navigation_right')` since you're using a class

Comment: @FabianBettag, Thanks for the notice that. I will change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your existing code, you are performing operation and then checking for disabled condition. Instead, store current and next element and if next element is available, perform operation. So if `next/prev` element is not available, no operation will be performed and you do not have to manually disable/enable button.

On prev, you will have to show previous element but you will have to show current element as well.

Since you do not want to go till last element, what you can do is to check if last element is fully visible on screen or not. If it is visible, disable button, else enable it.

```js
function enableDisableButtonState(context, value) {
  $('[class^=navigation_]').attr('disabled', false);
  $(context).attr('disabled', value);
}

$('.navigation_right').click(function() {
  var current = $('.current');
  var nextEl = current.next();
  var lastArticle = $('article:last');
  if (nextEl.length > 0) {
    current.removeClass('current').hide();
    nextEl.addClass('current').show();
  }
  var isInBounds = lastArticle.position().left < ($(document).width() - lastArticle.width());
  enableDisableButtonState(this, isInBounds);
});

$('.navigation_left').click(function() {
  var current = $('.current');
  var prevEL = current.prev();
  if (prevEL.length > 0) {
    current.removeClass('current');
    prevEL.addClass('current').show();
  }
  enableDisableButtonState(this, prevEL.is(':first-child'));
});
```

**Sample Code:**

```js
new WOW().init();
(function() {
  function scrollHorizontally(e) {
    e = window.event || e;
    var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
    document.getElementById('gentags').scrollLeft -= (delta * 40); // Multiplied by 40
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  if (document.getElementById('gentags').addEventListener) {
    // IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
    document.getElementById('gentags').addEventListener("mousewheel", scrollHorizontally, false);
    // Firefox
    document.getElementById('gentags').addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", scrollHorizontally, false);
  } else {
    // IE 6/7/8
    document.getElementById('gentags').attachEvent("onmousewheel", scrollHorizontally);
  }
})();

function enableDisableButtonState(context, value) {
  $('[class^=navigation_]').attr('disabled', false);
  $(context).attr('disabled', value);
}

$('.navigation_right').click(function() {
  var current = $('.current');
  var nextEl = current.next();
  var lastArticle = $('article:last');
  if (nextEl.length > 0) {
    current.removeClass('current').hide();
    nextEl.addClass('current').show();
  }
  var isInBounds = lastArticle.position().left < ($(document).width() - lastArticle.width());
  enableDisableButtonState(this, isInBounds);
});

$('.navigation_left').click(function() {
  var current = $('.current');
  var prevEL = current.prev();
  if (prevEL.length > 0) {
    current.removeClass('current');
    prevEL.addClass('current').show();
  }
  enableDisableButtonState(this, prevEL.is(':first-child'));
});
```

```css
#gentags {
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: -.25em;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#gentags>div {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 250%;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
  /* remove scrollbar space */
  background: transparent;
  /* optional: just make scrollbar invisible */
}


/* optional: show position indicator in red */

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: transparent;
}

.horizontal_scroll .full_screen_100 article {
  width: 11.58%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  border-left: solid 1px #E2E2E2;
}

.active_div {
  display: none;
}


/*Navigation style*/

.horizontal_scroll_icon_pre_next {
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  /* padding: 0 20px;*/
}

.horizontal_scroll_icon_pre_next button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  font-size: 0;
  color: #7b7b7b;
  display: none;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.horizontal_scroll_icon_pre_next button.navigation_left {
  float: left;
}

.horizontal_scroll_icon_pre_next button.navigation_right {
  float: right;
}

.horizontal_scroll_icon_pre_next button.active {
  display: block;
}

.horizontal_scroll_icon_pre_next button span {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.horizontal_scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}

button[class^='navigation_'] {
  transition: 0.4s;
}

button[class^='navigation_']:disabled {
  opacity: 0.2;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/animatecss/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.linearicons.com/free/1.0.0/icon-font.min.css">
<!--icon-->
<div class="active_div">
  <h2>I want to display this div when articles 7 comes on screen</h2>
</div>

<div id="gentags">
  <div class="horizontal_scroll">
    <div class="full_screen_100" id="left_scroll">
      <article class="wow fadeInUp first current">
        <div>
          <p class="scroll_number">01</p><span class="page_slogan">Hover me and scroll mouse wheel</span></div>
      </article>
      <article class="wow fadeInUp">
        <div>
          <p class="scroll_number">02</p><span class="page_slogan">Hover me and scroll mouse wheel </span></div>
      </article>
      <article class="wow fadeInUp">
        <div>
          <p class="scroll_number">03</p><span class="page_slogan">Hover me and scroll mouse wheel</span></div>
      </article>
      <article class="wow fadeInUp">
        <div>
          <p class="scroll_number">04</p><span class="page_slogan">Hover me and scroll mouse wheel</span></div>
      </article>
      <article class="wow fadeInUp">
        <div>
          <p class="scroll_number">05</p><span class="page_slogan">Hover me and scroll mouse wheel</span></div>
      </article>
      <article class="wow fadeInUp">
        <div>
          <p class="scroll_number">06</p><span class="page_slogan">Hover me and scroll mouse wheel</span></div>
      </article>
      <article class="wow fadeInUp">
        <div>
          <p class="scroll_number">07</p><span class="page_slogan">Hover me and scroll mouse wheel</span></div>
      </article>
      <article class="wow fadeInUp last">
        <div>
          <p class="scroll_number">08</p><span class="page_slogan">Hover me and scroll mouse wheel</span></div>
      </article>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="horizontal_scroll_icon_pre_next">
  <button class="navigation_left active" disabled><span class="lnr lnr-arrow-left"></span>Previous</button>
  <button class="navigation_right active"><span class="lnr lnr-arrow-right"></span>Next</button>
</div>
<!--horizontal_scroll_navigation-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.2/wow.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's working perfectly. I want to know can we stop the event on the last article displaying on screen? I mean if last article display on screen than next event stop.

Comment: I have total 8 articles, I am displaying 4 on page load. When the user clicked on next then it will display the next article. now the output on the screen will be 2,3,4,5. then again clicked next then 3,4,5,6 than 4,5,6,7 next 5,6,7,8. then stop next event.Now user can only be clicked on the previous button.

Comment: I just need output on the screen 5,6,7,8 articles. it's displaying only 8 articles until the click event stop

Comment: From where you learn this kind of script Because I am taking more than 4-5 days to solve this issue and you are solving this issue within 5 min.Relay appreciate your quick response. upvote from my side.

Comment: @NarendraVerma I've been there. Took years and still I have an ocean to learn. Just try to keep things simple and question your every line of code and you will be at this level in no time. Have a good day :-)

Comment: Can you help me out in this link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47344201/how-to-use-scroll-animation-on-the-horizontal-scroll

Answer (score 0):

try with some changes in code

```js
new WOW().init();
(function() {
  function scrollHorizontally(e) {
e = window.event || e;
var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
document.getElementById('gentags').scrollLeft -= (delta * 40); // Multiplied by 40
e.preventDefault();
  }
  if (document.getElementById('gentags').addEventListener) {
// IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
document.getElementById('gentags').addEventListener("mousewheel", scrollHorizontally, false);
// Firefox
document.getElementById('gentags').addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", scrollHorizontally, false);
  } else {
// IE 6/7/8
document.getElementById('gentags').attachEvent("onmousewheel", scrollHorizontally);
  }
})();

$('.navigation_right').click(function() {
  var current = $('.current');
  var nextEl = current.next();

   if($('.current').hasClass('last'))
   {
 $('.navigation_right').removeClass('active');
 $('.navigation_left').addClass('active');
   }
  if(nextEl.length > 0) {
current.removeClass('current').hide();
nextEl.addClass('current').show();
  }
});

$('.navigation_left').click(function() {
  var current = $('.current');
  var prevEL = current.prev();
if($('.current').hasClass('first'))
{
 $('.navigation_left').removeClass('active');
$('.navigation_right').addClass('active');
}
  if(prevEL.length > 0) {
current.removeClass('current');
prevEL.addClass('current').show();
  }
});
```

```css
#gentags {
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: -.25em;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#gentags>div {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 250%;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
  /* remove scrollbar space */
  background: transparent;
  /* optional: just make scrollbar invisible */
}


/* optional: show position indicator in red */

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: transparent;
}

.horizontal_scroll .full_screen_100 article {
  width: 11.58%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  border-left: solid 1px #E2E2E2;
}

.active_div {
  display: none;
}


/*Navigation style*/

.horizontal_scroll_icon_pre_next {
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  /* padding: 0 20px;*/
}

.horizontal_scroll_icon_pre_next button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  font-size: 0;
  color: #7b7b7b;
  display: none;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.horizontal_scroll_icon_pre_next button.navigation_left {
  float: left;
}

.horizontal_scroll_icon_pre_next button.navigation_right {
  float: right;
}

.horizontal_scroll_icon_pre_next button.active {
  display: block;
}

.horizontal_scroll_icon_pre_next button span {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/animatecss/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.linearicons.com/free/1.0.0/icon-font.min.css">
<!--icon-->
<div class="active_div">
  <h2>I want to display this div when articles 7 comes on screen</h2>
</div>

<div id="gentags">
  <div class="horizontal_scroll">
    <div class="full_screen_100" id="left_scroll">
      <article class="wow fadeInUp first current">
        <div>
          <p class="scroll_number">01</p><span class="page_slogan">Hover me and scroll mouse wheel</span></div>
      </article>
      <article class="wow fadeInUp">
        <div>
          <p class="scroll_number">02</p><span class="page_slogan">Hover me and scroll mouse wheel </span></div>
      </article>
      <article class="wow fadeInUp">
        <div>
          <p class="scroll_number">03</p><span class="page_slogan">Hover me and scroll mouse wheel</span></div>
      </article>
      <article class="wow fadeInUp">
        <div>
          <p class="scroll_number">04</p><span class="page_slogan">Hover me and scroll mouse wheel</span></div>
      </article>
      <article class="wow fadeInUp">
        <div>
          <p class="scroll_number">05</p><span class="page_slogan">Hover me and scroll mouse wheel</span></div>
      </article>
      <article class="wow fadeInUp">
        <div>
          <p class="scroll_number">06</p><span class="page_slogan">Hover me and scroll mouse wheel</span></div>
      </article>
      <article class="wow fadeInUp">
        <div>
          <p class="scroll_number">07</p><span class="page_slogan">Hover me and scroll mouse wheel</span></div>
      </article>
      <article class="wow fadeInUp last">
        <div>
          <p class="scroll_number">08</p><span class="page_slogan">Hover me and scroll mouse wheel</span></div>
      </article>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="horizontal_scroll_icon_pre_next">
  <button class="navigation_left active"><span class="lnr lnr-arrow-left"></span>Previous</button>
  <button class="navigation_right active"><span class="lnr lnr-arrow-right"></span>Next</button>
</div>
<!--horizontal_scroll_navigation-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.2/wow.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: the Previous button is not working properly. It's changing the content on the same place

Comment: No, In the snippet also the same issue.Just clicked on Next button 2-3 times and then clicked on the previous button. You will understand the issue.

Comment: because you only visible `current` section thats why

Comment: Any other option to handle that ?

Comment: i solve your prev next button visible hide on first last record

Comment: Sorry @Bhargav, But I haven't got proper resolution. Now the issue on only previous record. It is displaying at the same pace.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with `next()` function.

**it will move only one box at a time it will not move multiple textboxes combined.** and you are adding '**current**' class to single box and removing as well at a time.

I would suggest you to take a look at it:

> http://www.menucool.com/jquery-slider

There are many custom options in this plugin as you are going jquery already.

Peace.